# What will the declarative sentence No shoes, no shirt, no service be in propositional logic?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I need to write the following declarative sentence in propositional
logic.

**No shoes, no shirt, no service.**

My solution is: **~p,~q, ~r** , is it correct or do i need to use implication **->** instead

Comment: "No shoes, no shirt, no service" is not a proposition and any of "shoes", "shirt", "service" are propositions, so you can't deny them. It just doesn't have a precise meaning, you can interpret "no shoes" as "there are no shoes" or "it is not allowed to use shoes" or in many other different ways

Comment: This is a sign that is commonly seen at gas stations and convenience stores in the U.S.  It means that if you're not wearing shoes or if you're not wearing a shirt then you can't get service.

Comment: You need a connective. What logical connective is ", " ? I don't know that one. It's not even incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No shoes, no shirt, no service" is a phrase that states that both shoes and shirt are required, in order to receive service. Therefore, the statement should read $\neg \operatorname{Shoes} \vee \neg \operatorname{Shirt} \to \neg \operatorname{Service}$ in propositional logic (where you may replace "Shoes", "Shirt", "Service" with variables).
Note that this is equivalent to $\operatorname{Service} \to \operatorname{Shoes} \wedge \operatorname{Shirt}$.

Answer (score 2):

"," is not a symbol of propositional logic. So that in itself says you have it wrong.

You need to think about what the phrase *means*: "If you have no shoes, or you have no shirt, then you will receive no service." Try translating that into propositional logic.

Comment: I'm guessing OP is using "," to mean $\land$.

Comment: @DanBrumleve - and I am 99.9% certain that the OP simply translated the "no"s in the original phrase to "$~$" and replaced the three elements with letters, without knowing what to do with the ",". So I pointed out that this isn't adequate, and gave the correct interpretation of the phrase,

Comment: "," did not mean ∧ in my case,